# Error: Returned error: The execution failed due to an exception. @ web3.eth.estimateGas

Tags: web3js, gas-estimate, bignumber

I am having problem using bignumber.js with web3:

```
const sender = '0xss';
const recipient = '0xxx';
const amount = 1000; // have to use Bignumber for more than 1000
const decimals = 18;
const amountHex = web3.utils.toHex(new BigNumber(`${amount}e+${decimals}`));
const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender);
const data = contract.methods.transfer(recipient, amountHex).encodeABI();
const estimateGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    from: sender,
    nonce: '0x' + count.toString(16),
    to: '0xff',
    data
});
```

I get error at estimateGas :

```
Error: Returned error: The execution failed due to an exception.
```

Comment: It means that `contract.methods.transfer` would fail if you called it with the given parameters.

Comment: But what's wrong?

Comment: You gotta do some debugging yourself dude. And if you're expecting any help here, then you should by the least include ALL the relevant information. For example, I have no idea what your `transfer` function looks like and what it could fail for, because you haven't bothered to post the code of this function!

Comment: okay. When I use Number instead of BigNumber, web3.utils.toHex(Number(`${amount}e${decimals}`)); then it work.

Comment: Hey, I use the exact same `${amount}e${decimals}` trick! Where did you learn that?

Comment: BTW, you should generally avoid using `Number` in your scripts. The value of `${amount}e${decimals}` is most likely larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, so you're at risk of getting an inaccurate value sent to your contracts.

Comment: I now see the problem in your code, I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Web3.js v0.x relies on `BigNumber`.

Web3.js v1.x relies on `BN`.

The fact that you're calling `web3.utils.toHex` implies that you're using Web3.js v1.x.

Also note that you don't need your amount as a hex string; you can use either an integer or a string which represents an integer (which can be in either decimal format or hexadecimal format) or a `BN` instance.

So in short, instead of this:

```
const amountHex = web3.utils.toHex(new BigNumber(`${amount}e+${decimals}`));
```

You can use either one of the following:

```
const amount = `${amount}e+${decimals}`;
const amount = web3.utils.toBN(`${amount}e+${decimals}`);
```

You may also be tempted to use this:

```
const amount = Number(`${amount}e+${decimals}`);
```

However, since the value represented by this string is most likely larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you should avoid this option as it will potentially yield an innaccurate value.

Comment: I use Number, const amount = Number(`${amount}e+${decimals}`);, but it does not support bignumber, when I put in 1000 for amount, it prompted bn.js error.

Comment: @Alvin: Have you read my answer? It actually recommends NOT to use this option. Have you tried either one of the options that it does suggest?

Comment: Note to readers: avoid ```web3.utils.toBN(`${amount}e+${decimals}`)```, as the `BN` class interprets the input string as hexadecimal.